# Uploaing image to server in titanium

Tags: java, android, web-services, image-uploading, titanium-android

I am trying to upload image from gallery to server,i am selecting the image and converting the image to bytes by using the following code.

```
Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery({

saveToPhotoGallery : true,
allowEditing : false,
      success : function(event) {   
    var myBlob = event.media;       
    var bytes = Ti.Utils.base64encode(myBlob);
    Ti.API.info('base64encode========='+bytes);
},      
allowImageEditing : true,
mediaTypes : [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO]
});
```

I am sending the above bytes String to server through webservice but image is not uploading.

same i have done in java,both strings are coming same upto some level but java string is huge compare to titanium provided.
by passing java string through web service i am able to upload image.
please help me how to resolve this thanks in advance.